# c# Custom Control Navigation

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of Custom Control Forms (i.e. login page, home page, etc.) that I want to be embedded within a "main form". Every time the user navigates to another page, only the content of the "main form" gets changed.

But the only way I can do this is to copy the contents of the Custom Controls and paste them into the "main form" - which is messy. Is there a standard way of doing this type of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Ok it sounds like possibly you want to use an MDI form or maybe to use user controls (switching out controls for the new pages and such).

Old:
Is it possible you are talking about ASP.net pages and wanting to use master pages?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a `Panel`. Put all the controls for each “embedded form” in a panel of its own. Then you can just show and hide the right panel to make controls appear and disappear.

Alternatively, if you want the user to be able to manually switch between the “pages”, you could consider using a `TabControl`.